# How to know which product variation has which Variation ID in WooCommerce REST API

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I'm using WooCommerce Rest APIs in wordpress to make an android application and i'm trying to get product variation from the product detail's response.I am getting product variations with its attributes and names in a list but i don't know how to check which variation has which Variation ID.

```
"attributes": [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Ships From",
        "position": 0,
        "visible": false,
        "variation": true,
        "options": [
            "China"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 20,
        "name": "Type",
        "position": 1,
        "visible": false,
        "variation": true,
        "options": [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 21,
        "name": "Length (m/ft)",
        "position": 2,
        "visible": false,
        "variation": true,
        "options": [
            "0.25 / 0.82",
            "0.5 / 1.64",
            "1 / 3.28",
            "1.5 / 4.92",
            "2 / 6.56"
        ]
    }
],
"default_attributes": [],
"variations": [
    158435,
    158436,
    158437,
    158438,
    158439,
    158440,
    158441,
    158442,
    158443,
    158444,
    158445,
    158446
],
```

here i have names and ID of attributes with everything and in below i have all ID of product variations but i don't know how to know that if i mix **China+1+"0.25 / 0.82** then which will be variation ID.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make another api call to wp-json/wc/v3/products/< product_id >/variations or make individual calls to  wp-json/wc/v3/products/< product_id >/variations/< variation_id > using those variations id's on the "variations" array and check which variation has which combination of attributes, there is no direct relation between the variation ID and the attributes it uses.

Comment: Actually this way i can get all the variations for a product but the problem is in showing these variations in application. Is i follow your above mentioned process i must need to loop through all the the objects and then i will get attributes for this Json object. if i have 100 variations for a product this loop will run 100 times and each times an inner loop to check variation attributes which will low down the speed. Even if i follow this way i don't have any order to check which one should be first and which one should be last etc. and can you please help me through code.

Comment: wordpress has already much delay in response. it is almost 3 seconds and if i loop through all objects this will take to 5-6 seconds that will ruin the application